# Translation of 我想会吗? - I thought, is it possible?

Tags: translation

Is my translation right?

Here's the context (conversation about Snowden):

A:     未证实的意思呢就是还没有去证实、证明它是一个事实。

B:     嗯。我想，会吗？他可能已经在暗中做安排了吧。

A:     这个只是他们的官方说法嘛，呵呵。

Does it mean different things in different contexts?

[Transcript of conversation](http://chinesepod.com/lessons/%E6%96%AF%E8%AF%BA%E7%99%BB%E4%B8%8E%E2%80%9C%E6%A3%B1%E9%95%9C%E9%97%A8%E2%80%9D%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> B: 嗯。我想，会吗？他可能已经在暗中做安排了吧。

First, this is a transcription of colloquial dialog, which means the lines can be fragmented and is not entirely grammatical.

Second, I can see how it can be ambiguous and misleading due to the punctuation. Actually, `他可能已经在暗中做安排了吧` is also a part of the 'thinking'. It could have been clearer if it had been punctuated this way:

> B: 嗯。我想：“会吗？他可能已经在暗中做安排了吧。”

Which makes the meaning obvious:

> B: Yes. I was thinking, is it possible that some arrangements had been done by him already, in secret.

Answer (score 2):

> Translation of 我想会吗? - I thought, is it possible?

"我想"：You don't need to translate this because this is called (Parenthesis，插入语). No real meaning. So just translate it as "Is it possible" is right.

It takes the same action like "you see" in English

I have a lot of flowers, **you see**, there are red,green,blue,yellow……

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the source or the whole conversation? I've read the dialogue a few times. I think 会吗 is a rhetorical question here. It means B doesn't believe what A says. And A replies 这个只是他们的官方说法嘛. A says it's just their official announcement. It can be just diplomatic parlance.

Comment: Sure, I added the link in my OP. It's around the middle, if you do a page find on 我想，会吗？, you'll see it.